# Is there any way to do Custom dynamic mapping of different number of columns in Azure dataflow or any other options to achieve this?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

My source (CSV file in ADLS) has header record(3 columns) , detail records(5 columns) and trailer record(2 columns) . The header record has less number of columns than the detail records. When I try to convert this csv file to parquet, i m getting the column count error using copy activity in ADF. So I tried using dataflow to do the mapping but still its considering only three columns and ignoring the other two columns in the detail records.
So please let me know how to achieve this using dataflow or any other azure services.

### Sample Data

```
1|~filename|~30122020
2|~Mark|~cse|~378|~2020
2|~John|~|~430|~2019
99|~3
```

Comment: It's not a valid csv format file, data factory considers the first row as the column schema. We can't do that with Data factory actives or Data Flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data factory will consider the first row as the column schema. Just for now, We can't do that with Data factory actives or Data Flow.

Comment: yeah we observed the same and is it possible to achieve the same using Azure databricks?

Comment: @Abuchand That is a hardcode way, I couldn't tell if it works. If you don't specify the delimiter, the row will be considered as one String or one column. Per my experience,  derived transform(split or regexSplit function) also won't works. No matter how you split the data, data factory still user the first row as the schema. In addition, you data may be different in each row(has different column), we can not split it in a exactly pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole line(without specifying delimiter). Then use derived transform(use split or regexSplit function) to check if it is header or detail record